# How to read a .csv file specific items that hold this contrait?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a pretty large file like this:

```
SynsetTerms,PosScore,NegScore
a prueba de,0.208333333333,0.0833333333333
a reacción,0,0.0625
a salvo,0.1875,0.0625
a través de,0.1875,0.0
a ultranza,0.125,0.0
```

I would like to place in a list all the `SynsetTerms` that has `POsScore` > 0 . How can I aproach this task with the `csv` python's module?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very simple, just parse the file and unpack the three values like so:

```
with open('text.csv') as text:
    # iterate the list except for the title line and grab desired items
    data = [a for a, b, c in list(csv.reader(text))[1:] if float(b) > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, Im not familiar with the  .csv module I did not know how to manage the header.

Comment: Yes, the reader creates a generator which you can cast to a list and slice to remove the title line.

Comment: I got a: `data = [a for a, b, c in list(csv.reader(text1))[1:] if float(b) > 0] ValueError: too many values to unpack` any idea of what happened?.

Comment: @skwoi You probably forgot an entry in one of your lines. Each line should have three values.